# Supplying two IC within a circuit with different voltage range (1.8v to 3.6v) and ( 4v to 5v) with battery power

Tags: batteries, amplifier, stm32

We are designing a circuit that has two ICs with different supply range.
it will use micro batteries as supply unit. 
What is the efficient way to feed two ICs together and waste minimum energy.
Of course, with the lowest possible cost.
any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: What is the nominal voltage of the battery? Are the batter(ies) connected in parallel or in serial?

Comment: @StefanWyss The circuit uses 3 * 1.5 micro batteries. they are connected in serial.

Comment: How much current does each IC draw? How long do you expect the device to operate? **Exactly** what kind of battery are you planning to use..."micro batteries" doesn't help.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson one of them uses 30 mA and the other one is an amplifier which at least uses 120mA (it depends on speaker). we doesn't have limit in this area but we want to have battery life to be as long as possible.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson micro batteries are L1154 watch batteries

Comment: @StefanWyss  thank you in advance

Comment: Is the 30mA chip the 1.8V one, or the 5V one?  Either way, you're not going to run your device very long with those batteries, if at all.

Comment: @TimWescott Yes, The 30mA chip is the 1.8V one. we will play a message and sleep until next command (interrupt with user request).

Comment: I'm sorry but you can't create a design if your requirements are "as long as possible" and "lowest possible cost". Those are contradictory requirements, and anything that we might suggest will fail to meet one of those design criteria...so why waste our breath? Please try to formulate realistic requirements.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson thank you for the advice; but we are at the beginning of the design process and do not know how much the circuit can be low power. Therefore, we do not know the optimal situation.I ask a person with the similar experience to express his/her opinion

Comment: What about "lowest possible cost"? Surely you have some idea of what your final cost should be. You must also have some idea about how long you expect to operate. Hours? Days? Months? Tell us about your design!

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I think something about 1-2 hours is OK! and about cost, I should say, There are a lot of things affect the price (including the way we purchase an IC and so many other), but I think something about 1 $ ( for Different voltage supply circuit unit) is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Elliot Aldersen mentioned in his comment, it is not easy to help you with your design if you give us only "vague" design criterias. Nevertheless, I will try to give you my 50 cents:

The "most efficient" and "lowest cost" might be to connect the 3 L1154 batteries in series (nominal 4.5V) directly to your amplifier with 4V-5V input voltage range.

For the 1.8V chip, you might want to use an efficient buck type DC/DC converter to transform the 4.5V input voltage from the L1154 batteries to a 1.8V output voltage (Example for such a buck converter: [TI TPS62243](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS62243-Q1)).

Edit 1:

One problem you might encounter is that your L1154 batteries might not be able to deliver a total of 150mA into the load, because these type of batteries have a large output resistance. At least you will have a significant voltage drop from the batteries, so that it will not be possible to directly connect the amplifier to these batteries.

If this is the case, you would need to change your design: Connect the 3 batteries in parallel (nominal 1.5V output voltage) and use two boost type DC/DC converters, one for 1.8 output voltage and one for 5V output voltage.

Comment: Thank you, could you please introduce an IC, buck type DC/DC converter?

Comment: How can any solution for so many unknowns be possible?

Comment: @paradisalprogrammer I added some further details to my anwer.